# Add remote printer to my laptops devices permanently

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, printer

I have 2 PC's (lets call them WORK and HOME, on 2 different networks), and i have a printer on the same LAN with the WORK pc. Both WORK pc and printer are connected to router with ethernet cable.

I want to add the WORK printer to my HOME pc devices, and for it to be accessible in other apps like any other LAN printer that can be easily added in the devices list.

I can configure my routers to port forward if needed, but i dont know the steps i have to take (or if it is even possible without VPN or other software) to connect my HOME pc to the remote printer, what IP address it would have, type of connection, port, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As first step, WORK should do
[Share your network printer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/share-your-network-printer-c9a152b5-59f3-b6f3-c99f-f39e5bf664c3)
via *Settings > Devices  > Printers & scanners*,
click the printer, select Manage, then Printer Properties, then
the Sharing tab where you can share the printer on the network.

Then in the HOME computer, look in *Explorer > Network*.
If you see the printer, then just double-click on it to install.

If the printer isn't visible, connect it to WORK via a USB cable and
ensure that the printer driver is installed and working, then try again.

You may also go to *Settings > Devices > Printers & scanners*, click
on "Add a printer or scanner" and try the other options in the dialog.

Comment: doesnt this require HOME and WORK to be on the same network?

Comment: I misunderstood "Both WORK pc and printer are connected to router with ethernet cable" to mean the same router, my mistake. Otherwise, you would need to create a virtual network that includes both computers over the internet. Candidates would include [Radmin VPN](https://www.radmin-vpn.com/), [Tailscale](https://tailscale.com/) and [ZeroTier](https://www.zerotier.com/) and perhaps others.